# terraform - add route to multiple route tables aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, terraform

I need to add the same route to multiple route tables in AWS. I want to use terraform for this. For a single table I can use something like:

```
resource "aws_route" "route" {
  route_table_id = "${var.routetableid}"
  destination_cidr_block = "${var.destcidrblock}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.vpn.id}"
}
```

However I'd like to add the route for every route_table_id that's specified by the user as a list. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terraform resources allow you to loop through them using the [count meta parameter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count).

In your case you could do something like this:

```
variable "route_tables" { type = "list" }

resource "aws_route" "route" {
  count = "${length(var.route_tables)}"
  route_table_id = "${element(var.route_tables, count.index)}"
  destination_cidr_block = "${var.destcidrblock}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.vpn.id}"
}
```

Where `route_tables` is a list of route table ids.

Comment: thanks, when I run it for the first time, it always comes back with the following error - running it the second time works fine - any ideas why?: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* module.vpn.aws_route.route[0]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_route.route.0: InvalidParameterValue: There is no route defined for '172.64.0.0/16' in the route table. Use CreateRoute instead.
 status code: 400, request id: b229d66a-e47b-40b2-acf5-6c4c4a8598ba

Comment: You'd need to show more of your Terraform config to see why. And it might deserve being in a separate question too